# How to work with fail reason

Tags: validation

Imagine that I have a method like `User::validate($data)`, and mostly the developer expects only that is returns a boolean (`true` mean "ok, validated with success"). But, in some specific cases, he need check *why* validation failed. What is the best way to check that?

**I thought in following ways:**

1. Use an argument like `User::validate($data, $throwsException = false)` that when `true`, will throws an exception if it fail -- instead of returns `false`;
2. Always throws an exception. So the developer need care about in catch exceptions of this method -- I personally don't like that;
3. Instead of returns a boolean, returns a string or const (like `FAIL_INVALID_NAME`), but uses `true` as success -- or another const, like `SUCCESS`;
4. Create an additional method like `User::validateWithException($data)` that, if it fails, throws an exception instead of return `false`;
5. Create an additional method like `User::validateReason($data)` that will returns a string with the validation result -- like `fail:invalid-name` or `success`;
6. Create an additional method like `User::getLastError()` that will returns a string or const with last error ocurred on class `User`, like after the validation method;

Comment: Specifically, [the answer I wrote to that other question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/274108/22815) would answer this one.

Comment: But I need returns it even in simple cases, where developer don't need know the fail reason, for instance?

Comment: The beauty of the solution I provided is the metadata is optional. Leave the fail reason null or `""` if you want.

Comment: So I should validate it, in simple cases, like `if($user->validate()->isSuccess())`, right?

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few of your cases above suggest throwing an exception when a validation fails.  This is typically not recommended as exceptions should be reserved for exceptional cases (e.g., service not available, timeouts, etc) and not normal program flow.  Also, exceptions are typically expensive operations.

Validations are expected to fail when the conditions are not met and should return values indicating this.

Per your question on what this should look like, one option would be to update your input and output to objects with a few properties.  Perhaps something like:

ValidationRequest

- $Data
- $StopOnFirstFailure
- Other validation behavior controlling properties

ValidationResponse

- $Success
- $FailureReasons

Take a look at one of the many validation frameworks out there and you'll see how these patterns are used.